# Non repeating character from a preset of characters

Tags: java

I would like to pick a random letter out of a list `B`, `C`, `D` at random order and would make sure that they do not repeat. I have tried this but it repeats the letters

```
public class Test {
    static Random r = new Random();    
    static char pickRandom(char... letters) {
        return letters[r.nextInt(letters.length)];
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(pickRandom('B', 'C', 'D'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should check, if character already taken, for example declare another one array which contains already taken character, so if character caontains in this array, try to select another character, OR you can simply use Collections.shuffle method(Collection knowledge required)

```
List<Character> solution = new ArrayList<>();
solution.add('a');
solution.add('Y');
solution.add('Z');
Collections.shuffle(solution);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will keep track of the last character that was generated. The program will keep generating a new character until the one being generated is not the same as the last.

```
char last = 0, next = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    do {
        last = next;
        next = pickRandom('B', 'C', 'D');
    } while (next == last);
    System.out.print(next);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `static` variable (`lastRandom` in the following code) to store the last random index and update it with the index of the character you return. Being the `static` variable, it will preserve the value until it is updated or the JVM exits.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    static Random r = new Random();
    static int lastRandom;

    static char pickRandom(char... letters) {
        int newRandom = r.nextInt(letters.length);
        while (newRandom == lastRandom)
            newRandom = r.nextInt(letters.length);
        lastRandom = newRandom;
        return letters[newRandom];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(pickRandom('B', 'C', 'D'));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
CDCBDBDCDC
```